# Modify a model field's data using South

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I have a model which I want to rename but also change its data. The model field, say`foo` contains char data `1` ... `6` and I want to map this data in following ways:

`1`, `2` -> `1` && `3`, `4` -> `2` && `5` -> `3` && `6` -> `4`

I did `convert_to_south` on my app, which created `0001_initial` and then changed new new field in `models.py` and did `schemamigration` which made `0002_initial.py`. Now how do I modify the existing data? Here are my migrations:

**0001_initial**

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding model 'Applicant'
        db.create_table(u'registrar_applicant', (
            (u'id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(primary_key=True)),
            ('registered_at', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)),
            ('workshop', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=20)),
            ('name', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=255)),
            ('semester', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=1)),
            ('python_experience', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=1)),
            ('phone_number', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=10, blank=True)),
            ('email', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.EmailField')(max_length=75)),
            ('solved_puzzle', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField')(default=False)),
        ))
        db.send_create_signal(u'registrar', ['Applicant'])


    def backwards(self, orm):
        # Deleting model 'Applicant'
        db.delete_table(u'registrar_applicant')


    models = {
        u'registrar.applicant': {
            'Meta': {'ordering': "['-solved_puzzle', 'registered_at', 'semester', 'name']", 'object_name': 'Applicant'},
            'email': ('django.db.models.fields.EmailField', [], {'max_length': '75'}),
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '255'}),
            'phone_number': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '10', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'python_experience': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '1'}),
            'registered_at': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'auto_now_add': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'semester': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '1'}),
            'solved_puzzle': ('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField', [], {'default': 'False'}),
            'workshop': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '20'})
        }
    }

    complete_apps = ['registrar']
```

**0002_initial**

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding model 'Applicant'
        db.create_table(u'registrar_applicant', (
            (u'id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(primary_key=True)),
            ('registered_at', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)),
            ('workshop', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=20)),
            ('name', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=255)),
            ('year', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=1)),
            ('python_experience', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=1)),
            ('phone_number', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=10, blank=True)),
            ('email', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.EmailField')(max_length=75)),
            ('solved_puzzle', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField')(default=False)),
        ))
        db.send_create_signal(u'registrar', ['Applicant'])


    def backwards(self, orm):
        # Deleting model 'Applicant'
        db.delete_table(u'registrar_applicant')


    models = {
        u'registrar.applicant': {
            'Meta': {'ordering': "['-solved_puzzle', 'registered_at', 'year', 'name']", 'object_name': 'Applicant'},
            'email': ('django.db.models.fields.EmailField', [], {'max_length': '75'}),
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '255'}),
            'phone_number': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '10', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'python_experience': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '1'}),
            'registered_at': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'auto_now_add': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'solved_puzzle': ('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField', [], {'default': 'False'}),
            'workshop': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '20'}),
            'year': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '1'})
        }
    }

    complete_apps = ['registrar']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you'll have to create a [data migration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html)

```
# Run this command from the shell
python manage.py datamigration <app_name> change_foo_values
```

This is will create a migration file named `0003_change_foo_values.py`. You will have to manually edit the file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from south.utils import datetime_utils as datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.db import models

class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        "Write your forwards methods here."
        # Note: Don't use "from appname.models import ModelName". 
        # Use orm.ModelName to refer to models in this application,
        # and orm['appname.ModelName'] for models in other applications.
        orm.Applicant.objects.filter(foo__in=['1', '2']).update(foo='1')
        orm.Applicant.objects.filter(foo__in=['3', '4']).update(foo='2')
        orm.Applicant.objects.filter(foo__in=['5', '6']).update(foo='3')

    def backwards(self, orm):
        "Write your backwards methods here."

         # This migration cannot be reversed
         pass    # don't do anything when running reverse migration
         # or
         raise RuntimeError("Cannot reverse this migration") # stop south from reverting beyond this migration
```

**Note**: You won't be able to go revert back to the previous values of the column. If that is not a problem then this is sufficient.

However, if you do want to be able to reverse the migration, I suggest creating a new field, that will hold the old value of the column for each row.

**PS:** Your migration files seem wrong. You should not have two `initial` migrations for one app. Did you run `convert_to_south` after renaming your model(which doesn't seem to have been renamed) again? You only need to run `convert_to_south` once, when initially converting an existing model to south. After that you need to create [schema migrations](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#changing-the-model). The simplest way would be to run the `schemamigration` management command with the appname, and `--auto` as arguments.

```
python manage.py schemamigration <app_name> --auto
```

**PPS:** If you want to rename a model, please create an empty migration and write the migration code yourself, just use [`db.rename_table`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/databaseapi.html#db-rename-table). IIRC south will delete your old table before creating a new one if you try to create auto schemamigrations after renaming the model.

```
python manage.py schemamigration <app_name> --empty rename_model_x_to_y
```

And in your migration file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from south.utils import datetime_utils as datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.db import models

class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        "Write your forwards methods here."
        # Note: Don't use "from appname.models import ModelName". 
        # Use orm.ModelName to refer to models in this application,
        # and orm['appname.ModelName'] for models in other applications.
        db.rename_table('old', 'new')

    def backwards(self, orm):
        "Write your backwards methods here."
        db.rename_table('new', 'old')
```

Comment: @Sourabh hey, I have updated the answer with instructions on how to rename a model, please take a look